# Django - Passing template context to form

Tags: python, html, css, django, web-services

As part of a question page for a forum app, each page contains multiple posts, one of which is a question. Each post may have many comments. However, because there are many posts per page, I do not know how to pass the post that each comment is assigned to up to the database.

I was thinking of using HiddenInput, but not sure how to implement it.

Code below:
question_page.html

```
<tr id="post-comment-row">
    <!-- Post a comment -->
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <tr>
            <form id="comment_form" method="post" action="."
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <!-- Display form -->
                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form -->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
            </form>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        Please login to post a comment
    {% endif %}
</tr>
```

views.py:

```
# Show each individual question
def show_question_page(request, module_name_slug, question_page_name_slug, post_context=None):
    context_dict = {}

    module = Module.objects.get(slug=module_name_slug)
    question_page = QuestionPage.objects.get(slug=question_page_name_slug)
    question_posts = QuestionPost.objects.filter(page=question_page)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post__in=question_posts)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Save user data to database

            # Save comment instance
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post_context
            comment.user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            comment.save()
        else:
            # Invalid form(s): Print errors to console/log
            print(comment_form.errors)
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm

    context_dict['question_posts'] = question_posts
    context_dict['question_page'] = question_page
    context_dict['comments'] = comments
    context_dict['module'] = module
    context_dict['comment_form'] = comment_form

    return render(request, 'forum/questionPage.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a url with [named group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) for `post.id` to capture the `id` of post for which comment is being created.

```
url(r'app/post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comment/create', show_question_page, name='create-comment')
```

You can pass `post.id` in action url of the form.

```
action={% url 'create-comment' post.id %}
```

And in view, you can get the passed `post_id` from request object and create a comment related to post.

```
    comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
    post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
    comment.post = get_object_or_404(QuestionPost, id=post_id)
    comment.user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Cheers mate! Stuck on that for a couple of hours in hell